# Replacing text in a DIV with different text

Tags: jquery

I've googled how to do this, and it doesn't seem hard, but it also doesn't seem to be working.

On this site: http://www.glassrailingsusa.com/glass-railing-gallery/

There is a dropdown of galleries. The page defaults to "All" images, but the box doesn't read "All". I can't change the plugin, so I figured I would just use jQuery to change the text.

This is my JS

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.fg-current-album').text('All');
});
</script>
```

This is the HTML of the dropdown (which isn't a select)

```
<div class="fg-dropdown">
<div class="fg-current-album fg-current-album-white">Exterior Railings</div>
<ul class="fg-dropdown-list fg-dropdown-list-white" style="display: none;">
  <li>All</li>
  <li>Exterior Railings</li>
  <li>Glass Gates</li>
  <li>Glass Railings</li>
  <li>Interior Railings</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I've tried adding the script in the header, and in the footer above the closing body tag. Neither seems to work. I also tried .html() which didn't work. Is it maybe when I'm calling the script? I'm not really sure how to debug this.

Comment: Can you explain "Not working"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely the place your JS is being called because after the page is completely loaded if you enter this in the browser Console it works:

```
 $('div.fg-current-album').text('All');
```

Maybe there is some async ajax going on that over writes that..

you could probably try a Timeout there like:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('div.fg-current-album').text('All'); }, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks Aram, the timeout works. I'll send a message to the plugin developer as well, as it really should be showing "All" if all the images show by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try double quotation just in case

```
$( "div.fg-current-album" ).text( "<p>All</p>" );
```